# How to add datetime field in AEM review step?

Tags: workflow, aem

I am developing a custom workflow, which should have a datetime field so that user can select a date and time schedule the workflow at review step.

How can I add add datetime field and schedule the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

AEM provides a [Dialog Participant Step](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/extending/workflows/wf-ref.html#Dialog%20Participant%20Step). This allows user to add custom dialog to workflow step. Following steps can be done to use custom dialog

1. Create a dialog and have a `datetime` xtype filed in that.
2. Use the OOTB Dialog Participant Step as review step to point to the dialog created in step 1 as explained in reference link.
3. The data selected by User while approval can be saved under payload or workflow metadata. It depends upon how you have specified value of name property as explained in reference link. Sometimes you would not want to save under the page as it would modify the page "modified timestamp". It would depend on use case you are trying to achieve.

Now this date selected in step 3 can be used to schedule using `AbsoluteTimeAutoAdvancer` or custom `AbsoluteTimeoutHandler` implementation.

For the dialog created in classic UI, you would need to [provide Touch UI dialog path](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__5gki-with_aem_6_1canyo.html) to make it compatible with AEM 6.1 as it expects a property `touchUiDialogPath`